# ElasticSearch filtered "OR" query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this ElasticSearch query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "term": { "fieldA": "A", "fieldB": "12345" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It returns data where both fieldA AND fieldB have matching values.

But I need data either if fieldA  = A OR fieldB  = 12345.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The answer from [ttomalak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9312230/ttomalak) doesn't seem to work because of syntax (at least for 6.2.0), but the idea is good. Try this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {"term": {"fieldA": "A"}},
                {"term": {"fieldB": "12345"}}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah typed it without elasticsearch console so mistaped some of them, your answer should be correct

Comment: No this is not a filter as it A) affects the ranking and B) Also ok in some cases if none of both term-match -- at least if you add more terms.